# Kernel Oops causing system crash when playing game - nvidia drivers

Tags: linux, linux-mint, nvidia

Hopefully this is the right place for this. I started getting random system crashes requiring while playing dota 2 on linux mint 17.3 running nvidia drivers. It would happen after a few minutes into a game - the screen freezes and the last fraction of a second of audio loops and the system is unresponsive requiring a hard reset.

At the time I thought it may be a hardware fault as it was a pretty old machine which I was planning on upgrading anyway. So I ended up getting a new mobo, cpu and ram (Gigabyte GA-H170N-WIFI, Intel Core i5 6500,    Corsair Vengeance LPX CMK16GX4M2A2133C13 16GB (2x8GB) DDR4) and kept the same GPU (GTX 750 Ti). I was still getting the same crashes. I then tried the following, none of which had any effect:

- Different GPU (GTX 950) - same issue
- Different power supply - same issue
- Different SSID with fresh OS install - same issue
  At this point I think a hardware fault is ruled out since it's an entirely new system.
- Upgrading to Linux Mint 18 beta
- Tried 3 different nvidia driver versions (for both GPUs that I tried)
- Tried upgrading kernel
- Tried upgrading BIOS
- enabling Vsync
- Dota 2 specific: -gl_disable_buffer_storage in launch options
- memtest

Eventually I worked out that if I tailed the kernel log while ssh'd from another machine I could see the error (it wasn't in the logs after reboot, however). This is what I was getting:

```
Jun 15 23:15:02 lucas-desktop kernel: [ 1218.461993] BUG: unable to handle kernel paging request at ffffaa0001f4c120
Jun 15 23:15:02 lucas-desktop kernel: [ 1218.461996] IP: [<ffffffff81194cc8>] free_pcppages_bulk+0x368/0x480
Jun 15 23:15:02 lucas-desktop kernel: [ 1218.462000] PGD 0 
Jun 15 23:15:02 lucas-desktop kernel: [ 1218.462001] Oops: 0002 [#1] SMP 
Jun 15 23:15:02 lucas-desktop kernel: [ 1218.462003] Modules linked in: rfcomm bnep binfmt_misc nls_iso8859_1 snd_hda_codec_hdmi arc4 nvidia_uvm(POE) snd_hda_codec_realtek snd_hda_codec_generic i915_bpo nvidia_drm(POE) nvidia_modeset(POE) intel_ips drm_kms_helper drm fb_sys_fops syscopyarea sysfillrect sysimgblt nvidia(POE) snd_hda_intel snd_hda_codec intel_rapl snd_hda_core iwlmvm snd_hwdep x86_pkg_temp_thermal intel_powerclamp coretemp mac80211 snd_pcm kvm_intel kvm joydev irqbypass input_leds snd_seq_midi snd_seq_midi_event crct10dif_pclmul btusb snd_rawmidi btrtl crc32_pclmul snd_seq aesni_intel snd_seq_device snd_timer aes_x86_64 iwlwifi lrw gf128mul glue_helper ablk_helper cryptd snd cfg80211 soundcore serio_raw mei_me shpchp mei hci_uart btbcm btqca btintel bluetooth wmi intel_lpss_acpi intel_lpss tpm_infineon mac_hid acpi_pad acpi_als kfifo_buf industrialio parport_pc ppdev lp parport autofs4 btrfs xor raid6_pq dm_mirror dm_region_hash dm_log hid_generic hid_roccat_savu hid_roccat hid_roccat_common usbhid psmouse igb e1000e dca ptp pps_core ahci i2c_algo_bit libahci video pinctrl_sunrisepoint i2c_hid pinctrl_intel hid fjes [last unloaded: cpuid]
Jun 15 23:15:02 lucas-desktop kernel: [ 1218.462031] CPU: 1 PID: 2601 Comm: steamwebhelper Tainted: P           OE   4.4.0-24-generic #43-Ubuntu
Jun 15 23:15:02 lucas-desktop kernel: [ 1218.462033] Hardware name: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd. To be filled by O.E.M./H170N-WIFI-CF, BIOS F4c 01/13/2016
Jun 15 23:15:02 lucas-desktop kernel: [ 1218.462034] task: ffff8800861ebb00 ti: ffff8803e869c000 task.ti: ffff8803e869c000
Jun 15 23:15:02 lucas-desktop kernel: [ 1218.462035] RIP: 0010:[<ffffffff81194cc8>]  [<ffffffff81194cc8>] free_pcppages_bulk+0x368/0x480
Jun 15 23:15:02 lucas-desktop kernel: [ 1218.462037] RSP: 0018:ffff8803e869fa90  EFLAGS: 00210002
Jun 15 23:15:02 lucas-desktop kernel: [ 1218.462037] RAX: ffffea0001ef9600 RBX: 0000000000000002 RCX: ffffaa0001f4c120
Jun 15 23:15:02 lucas-desktop kernel: [ 1218.462038] RDX: 0000000000000658 RSI: ffffea00019b7120 RDI: dead000000000100
Jun 15 23:15:02 lucas-desktop kernel: [ 1218.462039] RBP: ffff8803e869fb00 R08: ffffea0001ef9700 R09: 0000000000200286
Jun 15 23:15:02 lucas-desktop kernel: [ 1218.462040] R10: 0000000000000009 R11: 000000000000000a R12: 000000000000065c
Jun 15 23:15:02 lucas-desktop kernel: [ 1218.462040] R13: 0000000000000001 R14: ffff8804767f97c0 R15: 0000000000000001
Jun 15 23:15:02 lucas-desktop kernel: [ 1218.462041] FS:  0000000000000000(0000) GS:ffff880476480000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
Jun 15 23:15:02 lucas-desktop kernel: [ 1218.462042] CS:  0010 DS: 002b ES: 002b CR0: 0000000080050033
Jun 15 23:15:02 lucas-desktop kernel: [ 1218.462043] CR2: ffffaa0001f4c120 CR3: 0000000002e0a000 CR4: 00000000003406e0
Jun 15 23:15:02 lucas-desktop kernel: [ 1218.462044] DR0: 0000000000000000 DR1: 0000000000000000 DR2: 0000000000000000
Jun 15 23:15:02 lucas-desktop kernel: [ 1218.462044] DR3: 0000000000000000 DR6: 00000000fffe0ff0 DR7: 0000000000000400
Jun 15 23:15:02 lucas-desktop kernel: [ 1218.462045] Stack:
Jun 15 23:15:02 lucas-desktop kernel: [ 1218.462046]  ffff8804767f9d40 ffff88047649a6e0 0000001063927020 ffff88047649a700
Jun 15 23:15:02 lucas-desktop kernel: [ 1218.462047]  ffff88047649a6f0 ffffea0001ef9740 0000000100000010 0000000000000198
Jun 15 23:15:02 lucas-desktop kernel: [ 1218.462048]  0000000000000000 ffff8804767f97c0 ffff88047649a6e0 000000000000001f
Jun 15 23:15:02 lucas-desktop kernel: [ 1218.462050] Call Trace:
Jun 15 23:15:02 lucas-desktop kernel: [ 1218.462052]  [<ffffffff8119510c>] free_hot_cold_page+0x18c/0x1c0
Jun 15 23:15:02 lucas-desktop kernel: [ 1218.462054]  [<ffffffff81195188>] free_hot_cold_page_list+0x48/0xb0
Jun 15 23:15:02 lucas-desktop kernel: [ 1218.462055]  [<ffffffff8119dbdb>] release_pages+0xdb/0x2b0
Jun 15 23:15:02 lucas-desktop kernel: [ 1218.462058]  [<ffffffff811d2e1d>] free_pages_and_swap_cache+0x7d/0x90
Jun 15 23:15:02 lucas-desktop kernel: [ 1218.462060]  [<ffffffff811bbbe6>] tlb_flush_mmu_free+0x36/0x60
Jun 15 23:15:02 lucas-desktop kernel: [ 1218.462062]  [<ffffffff811bdddc>] unmap_page_range+0x58c/0x7a0
Jun 15 23:15:02 lucas-desktop kernel: [ 1218.462063]  [<ffffffff811be06d>] unmap_single_vma+0x7d/0xe0
Jun 15 23:15:02 lucas-desktop kernel: [ 1218.462065]  [<ffffffff811beb31>] unmap_vmas+0x51/0xa0
Jun 15 23:15:02 lucas-desktop kernel: [ 1218.462066]  [<ffffffff811c8027>] exit_mmap+0xa7/0x170
Jun 15 23:15:02 lucas-desktop kernel: [ 1218.462068]  [<ffffffff8107df77>] mmput+0x57/0x130
Jun 15 23:15:02 lucas-desktop kernel: [ 1218.462070]  [<ffffffff81083cad>] do_exit+0x27d/0xae0
Jun 15 23:15:02 lucas-desktop kernel: [ 1218.462072]  [<ffffffff810ac950>] ? wake_up_state+0x10/0x20
Jun 15 23:15:02 lucas-desktop kernel: [ 1218.462074]  [<ffffffff8108df0e>] ? signal_wake_up_state+0x1e/0x30
Jun 15 23:15:02 lucas-desktop kernel: [ 1218.462075]  [<ffffffff81084593>] do_group_exit+0x43/0xb0
Jun 15 23:15:02 lucas-desktop kernel: [ 1218.462076]  [<ffffffff81084614>] SyS_exit_group+0x14/0x20
Jun 15 23:15:02 lucas-desktop kernel: [ 1218.462078]  [<ffffffff81003dcc>] do_fast_syscall_32+0x9c/0x170
Jun 15 23:15:02 lucas-desktop kernel: [ 1218.462080]  [<ffffffff818281b2>] sysenter_flags_fixed+0x8/0x12
Jun 15 23:15:02 lucas-desktop kernel: [ 1218.462081] Code: 00 00 49 89 48 20 49 89 40 28 48 89 10 e9 d8 fe ff ff 48 8b 70 20 48 8b 48 28 48 bf 00 01 00 00 00 00 ad de 4c 21 e2 48 89 4e 08 <48> 89 31 89 d9 48 8d 34 49 48 89 78 20 48 bf 00 02 00 00 00 00 
Jun 15 23:15:02 lucas-desktop kernel: [ 1218.462097] RIP  [<ffffffff81194cc8>] free_pcppages_bulk+0x368/0x480
Jun 15 23:15:02 lucas-desktop kernel: [ 1218.462098]  RSP <ffff8803e869fa90>
Jun 15 23:15:02 lucas-desktop kernel: [ 1218.462099] CR2: ffffaa0001f4c120
Jun 15 23:15:02 lucas-desktop kernel: [ 1218.462100] ---[ end trace c04c45f3b1d98e2f ]---
Jun 15 23:15:02 lucas-desktop kernel: [ 1218.462101] Fixing recursive fault but reboot is needed!
Jun 15 23:15:02 lucas-desktop kernel: [ 1218.477219] BUG: unable to handle kernel NULL pointer dereference at 0000000000000020
Jun 15 23:15:02 lucas-desktop kernel: [ 1218.477221] IP: [<ffffffffc0d2261a>] _nv011492rm+0x3a/0xd0 [nvidia]
Jun 15 23:15:02 lucas-desktop kernel: [ 1218.477306] PGD 0 
Jun 15 23:15:02 lucas-desktop kernel: [ 1218.477307] Oops: 0002 [#2] SMP 
Jun 15 23:15:02 lucas-desktop kernel: [ 1218.477309] Modules linked in: rfcomm bnep binfmt_misc nls_iso8859_1 snd_hda_codec_hdmi arc4 nvidia_uvm(POE) snd_hda_codec_realtek snd_hda_codec_generic i915_bpo nvidia_drm(POE) nvidia_modeset(POE) intel_ips drm_kms_helper drm fb_sys_fops syscopyarea sysfillrect sysimgblt nvidia(POE) snd_hda_intel snd_hda_codec intel_rapl snd_hda_core iwlmvm snd_hwdep x86_pkg_temp_thermal intel_powerclamp coretemp mac80211 snd_pcm kvm_intel kvm joydev irqbypass input_leds snd_seq_midi snd_seq_midi_event crct10dif_pclmul btusb snd_rawmidi btrtl crc32_pclmul snd_seq aesni_intel snd_seq_device snd_timer aes_x86_64 iwlwifi lrw gf128mul glue_helper ablk_helper cryptd snd cfg80211 soundcore serio_raw mei_me shpchp mei hci_uart btbcm btqca btintel bluetooth wmi intel_lpss_acpi intel_lpss tpm_infineon mac_hid acpi_pad acpi_als kfifo_buf industrialio parport_pc ppdev lp parport autofs4 btrfs xor raid6_pq dm_mirror dm_region_hash dm_log hid_generic hid_roccat_savu hid_roccat hid_roccat_common usbhid psmouse igb e1000e dca ptp pps_core ahci i2c_algo_bit libahci video pinctrl_sunrisepoint i2c_hid pinctrl_intel hid fjes [last unloaded: cpuid]
Jun 15 23:15:02 lucas-desktop kernel: [ 1218.477343] CPU: 0 PID: 1084 Comm: Xorg Tainted: P      D    OE   4.4.0-24-generic #43-Ubuntu
Jun 15 23:15:02 lucas-desktop kernel: [ 1218.477344] Hardware name: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd. To be filled by O.E.M./H170N-WIFI-CF, BIOS F4c 01/13/2016
Jun 15 23:15:02 lucas-desktop kernel: [ 1218.477345] task: ffff880460038ec0 ti: ffff88045d93c000 task.ti: ffff88045d93c000
Jun 15 23:15:02 lucas-desktop kernel: [ 1218.477346] RIP: 0010:[<ffffffffc0d2261a>]  [<ffffffffc0d2261a>] _nv011492rm+0x3a/0xd0 [nvidia]
Jun 15 23:15:02 lucas-desktop kernel: [ 1218.477418] RSP: 0018:ffff88045d93fba0  EFLAGS: 00010206
Jun 15 23:15:02 lucas-desktop kernel: [ 1218.477419] RAX: 00000000007b0000 RBX: 0000000000000001 RCX: 0000000000000020
Jun 15 23:15:02 lucas-desktop kernel: [ 1218.477420] RDX: 0000000000000001 RSI: ffff88045dec5c24 RDI: 0000000000000001
Jun 15 23:15:02 lucas-desktop kernel: [ 1218.477421] RBP: ffff88045dec5c20 R08: ffffffffc11524f0 R09: 0000000000000000
Jun 15 23:15:02 lucas-desktop kernel: [ 1218.477421] R10: ffff880461fe8c00 R11: ffffffffc0d4a0b0 R12: ffff88045ce0a808
Jun 15 23:15:02 lucas-desktop kernel: [ 1218.477422] R13: ffff88045ce0a810 R14: ffff88045cd14008 R15: ffff880460f87008
Jun 15 23:15:02 lucas-desktop kernel: [ 1218.477423] FS:  00007fe2d7a66a00(0000) GS:ffff880476400000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
Jun 15 23:15:02 lucas-desktop kernel: [ 1218.477424] CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
Jun 15 23:15:02 lucas-desktop kernel: [ 1218.477425] CR2: 0000000000000020 CR3: 000000046190d000 CR4: 00000000003406f0
Jun 15 23:15:02 lucas-desktop kernel: [ 1218.477425] DR0: 0000000000000000 DR1: 0000000000000000 DR2: 0000000000000000
Jun 15 23:15:02 lucas-desktop kernel: [ 1218.477426] DR3: 0000000000000000 DR6: 00000000fffe0ff0 DR7: 0000000000000400
Jun 15 23:15:02 lucas-desktop kernel: [ 1218.477427] Stack:
Jun 15 23:15:02 lucas-desktop kernel: [ 1218.477427]  ffffffff90ffc789 ffff880462a7c008 ffffffffc0d6d8fa 0000000000000000
Jun 15 23:15:02 lucas-desktop kernel: [ 1218.477429]  0000000000000000 0000000000000000 ffffffffc0a43461 ffff88045d97ac08
Jun 15 23:15:02 lucas-desktop kernel: [ 1218.477430]  0000000000000000 0000000000000000 ffff8804602d3408 ffff8803ccfba548
Jun 15 23:15:02 lucas-desktop kernel: [ 1218.477432] Call Trace:
Jun 15 23:15:02 lucas-desktop kernel: [ 1218.477497]  [<ffffffffc0d6d8fa>] ? _nv012701rm+0x2a/0x90 [nvidia]
Jun 15 23:15:02 lucas-desktop kernel: [ 1218.477582]  [<ffffffffc0a43461>] ? _nv007552rm+0x101/0x1090 [nvidia]
Jun 15 23:15:02 lucas-desktop kernel: [ 1218.477665]  [<ffffffffc0a3dc81>] ? _nv007551rm+0x101/0x250 [nvidia]
Jun 15 23:15:02 lucas-desktop kernel: [ 1218.477748]  [<ffffffffc0a3dc0b>] ? _nv007551rm+0x8b/0x250 [nvidia]
Jun 15 23:15:02 lucas-desktop kernel: [ 1218.477816]  [<ffffffffc0d2d82e>] ? _nv000897rm+0x1c7e/0x1e40 [nvidia]
Jun 15 23:15:02 lucas-desktop kernel: [ 1218.477883]  [<ffffffffc0d2cef9>] ? _nv000897rm+0x1349/0x1e40 [nvidia]
Jun 15 23:15:02 lucas-desktop kernel: [ 1218.477950]  [<ffffffffc0d2db19>] ? _nv000845rm+0x129/0x4a0 [nvidia]
Jun 15 23:15:02 lucas-desktop kernel: [ 1218.478016]  [<ffffffffc0d2dada>] ? _nv000845rm+0xea/0x4a0 [nvidia]
Jun 15 23:15:02 lucas-desktop kernel: [ 1218.478082]  [<ffffffffc0d353c7>] ? _nv003162rm+0x1797/0x3280 [nvidia]
Jun 15 23:15:02 lucas-desktop kernel: [ 1218.478145]  [<ffffffffc0da2240>] ? _nv000839rm+0x250/0x800 [nvidia]
Jun 15 23:15:02 lucas-desktop kernel: [ 1218.478208]  [<ffffffffc0dac133>] ? rm_ioctl+0x73/0x100 [nvidia]
Jun 15 23:15:02 lucas-desktop kernel: [ 1218.478215]  [<ffffffffc1f55400>] ? _nv000320kms+0x50/0x70 [nvidia_modeset]
Jun 15 23:15:02 lucas-desktop kernel: [ 1218.478249]  [<ffffffffc083cca4>] ? nvidia_ioctl+0x144/0x4b0 [nvidia]
Jun 15 23:15:02 lucas-desktop kernel: [ 1218.478285]  [<ffffffffc083b080>] ? nvidia_frontend_compat_ioctl+0x40/0x50 [nvidia]
Jun 15 23:15:02 lucas-desktop kernel: [ 1218.478321]  [<ffffffffc083b09e>] ? nvidia_frontend_unlocked_ioctl+0xe/0x10 [nvidia]
Jun 15 23:15:02 lucas-desktop kernel: [ 1218.478324]  [<ffffffff8122062f>] ? do_vfs_ioctl+0x29f/0x490
Jun 15 23:15:02 lucas-desktop kernel: [ 1218.478326]  [<ffffffff8103b32d>] ? fpu__restore_sig+0x4d/0x60
Jun 15 23:15:02 lucas-desktop kernel: [ 1218.478327]  [<ffffffff81220899>] ? SyS_ioctl+0x79/0x90
Jun 15 23:15:02 lucas-desktop kernel: [ 1218.478330]  [<ffffffff81825bf2>] ? entry_SYSCALL_64_fastpath+0x16/0x71
Jun 15 23:15:02 lucas-desktop kernel: [ 1218.478330] Code: c7 45 04 00 00 00 00 48 8d 75 04 89 df e8 8f f0 ff ff 48 85 c0 74 02 8b b8 90 1d 00 00 85 ff 74 e6 48 85 c0 74 13 68 89 c7 ff 90 <18> 01 00 20 89 c2 48 83 c5 08 89 90 5b c3 c7 45 04 00 00 00 00 
Jun 15 23:15:02 lucas-desktop kernel: [ 1218.478346] RIP  [<ffffffffc0d2261a>] _nv011492rm+0x3a/0xd0 [nvidia]
Jun 15 23:15:02 lucas-desktop kernel: [ 1218.478414]  RSP <ffff88045d93fba0>
Jun 15 23:15:02 lucas-desktop kernel: [ 1218.478414] CR2: 0000000000000020
Jun 15 23:15:02 lucas-desktop kernel: [ 1218.478416] ---[ end trace c04c45f3b1d98e30 ]---
```

I assume the issue here is the 'unable to handle kernel paging request' part but it's beyond my level of expertise at this point.

Currently, my system is:

- Gigabyte GA-H170N-WIFI
- Intel Core i5 6500
- Corsair Vengeance LPX CMK16GX4M2A2133C13 16GB (2x8GB) DDR4
- GTX 750 Ti
- Linux Mint 18 beta
- nvidia 367 driver

I'm at a loss as to what could be causing this since I've ruled out a hardware issue and it still happens across different os versions and kernel versions. I've not been able to find anyone else that has had my set of problems.

Any advice as to what I can troubleshoot next would be really helpful. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Proprietary driver blobs are hard to debug. Report the issue to NVIDIA. If NVIDIA driver did some small damage earlier inside kernel which did not tripped immediately then this damage would still be tripped at some later point which is happened with you when steamwebhelper tried to exit().

Comment: I seem to get the same error 'unable to handle kernel paging request' when running memtester while in the OS. I then ran a full memtest from a live usb but found no errors in 3 passes. Any ideas?

Comment: Unload any proprietary modules from kernel and try memtester again. Try to play the game with nouveau. If problem persists then this is a kernel regression which should be reported to kernel devs.